# Python3.pc file not found with pkg-config

Tags: python, c, makefile, pkg-config

I am on a Ubuntu 14.04 machine that have python3 installed. In a make file I have flags that looks like this:

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -std=c11 -g -DNDEBUG `pkg-config --cflags python3`
```

I am getting the error when I run my make file:

```
gcc -Wall -std=c11 -g -DNDEBUG `pkg-config --cflags python3` -fPIC   -c -o calmodule.o calmodule.c
Package python3 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `python3.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'python3' found
gcc -shared  calmodule.o calutil.o -o Cal.so
```

I checked the pkg-config folder and found nothing for python in there:

```
  % la /usr/lib/pkgconfig
total 20K
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 288 Jul 22  2015 dbus-python.pc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 452 Jul 22  2015 ibus-table.pc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 245 Jul 12  2014 libquvi-scripts.pc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 379 Jul 10  2014 pm-utils.pc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 366 Sep 30 08:02 valgrind.pc
```

Shouldn't there be a `python3.pc` file in there? Or at the very least a specific one like `python3.4.pc` ?

Or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Try `pkg-config --list-all | grep ^python`

Comment: @falsetru No results.  Not including grep on that it is a fairly short list and I can manually also see no results. I do have python 2 and python 3 installed yet nothing. They were installed via `apt-get`. My `python3 --version` output gives me: `Python 3.4.3+`

Answer (score 7):

To resolve the problem it looks like I needed to get the `python3-dev` package.

Simply ran:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```